# Increment a property value of an element in array object mongodb-node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am trying to increment a value of an element here's my array object

```
"options": [
    {
        "key": "banana",
        "votes": 0
    },
    {
        "key": "apple",
        "votes": 0
    },
    {
        "key": "mango",
        "votes": 0
    },
    {
        "key": "grapes",
        "votes": 0
    }
]
```

im trying to increment the votes value of the selected 
`item` while also matching the `id` of that data

```
  db().collection('polls').update( 
            { _id: id, "options.key": item },
            {$set:  { $inc: { "options.$.votes" : 1 } }})
```

But it didn't work... the `db()` here is a function that returns the db.. im not getting any errors.

here is the full data

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5aae26203ab1cc0f15e43dc6"
    },
    "author": "me",
    "title": "fruits you love the most",
    "options": [
        {
            "key": "banana",
            "votes": 0
        },
        {
            "key": "apple",
            "votes": 0
        },
        {
            "key": "mango",
            "votes": 0
        },
        {
            "key": "grapes",
            "votes": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$set` and try. It should work then. Also, the `db` should be used without paranthesis like `db` and not `db()`:

```
db.collection('polls').update( 
   { _id: id, "options.key": item },
   { $inc: { "options.$.votes" : 1 } }
)
```

If you are running this query directly in your mongodb shell then you need to specify `_id: ObjectId(id)` in your query so your query will be:

```
var id = '5aaf66812b0e3813178a8a14'
db.collection('polls').update( 
   { _id: ObjectId(id), "options.key": item },
   { $inc: { "options.$.votes" : 1 } }
)
```

Comment: Are you running this script from mongoose or directly on mongodb?

Comment: If its directly on mongodb then you should be using `_id: ObjectId(id)`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing thing all correct but only one mistake is **$inc** should not be inside **$set**.

Following will fulfil your requirement.

```
    db.collection.update(
       {"options.key": "banana" },
       { $inc: { "options.$.votes" : 1 } }
    )
```

Comment: this works but i also want to match the data id so it just updates that particular data..

Comment: then you can add data id field too in search filter. :)